# Element with position absolute being placed relative to non-positioned parent element

Tags: html, css, css-position

My understanding of CSS positioning has been, for a while, that elements with `position:absolute` and `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom` specified are placed using those numbers relative to the closest ancestor element with `position:relative` or relative to the document if there's no such ancestor element.

While creating a test script to explain CSS positioning to someone, I came across what seems, to me, to be very awkward behavior. As you can see @ http://jsbin.com/axocUCo/1/edit?html,output, I've got the `.child` to be `position:absolute`, it's parent `.parent` has no positioning and it's parent `.grand_parent` has `position:relative`. I've set `.child` to have `left:0` and `top:0`. But the child's being placed relative to `.parent` and not `.grand_parent`. Why is it so?

Is my understanding of CSS positioning, somehow, flawed? Or, am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [understanding is actually right](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) and it is working as expected, because you have a problem with your cascading in the css. The child is a `<div>`, hence having the style defined in the ` for the divs, which includes margins. Try adding this to the child:

```
 #absolute_relative .child {
   margin: 0;
   }
```

Note: it seemed a strange behaviour because both the child and parent had the same margin, thus it seemed like if the child was relative to the parent, but it wasn't.

[Proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/eKOnOJO/1/](http://jsbin.com/eKOnOJO/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct and it is behaving the same in your sample. Its the margins and percentage width and heights that is making it appear as it is positioned relative to parent and not grandParent.

You can try setting the right and bottom properties here and see the difference clearly.

```
  #absolute_relative .child{
        position: absolute;
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Also here is a fiddle which clearly demonstrates this behavior: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM8kE/1/)